# How to reproduce the Stanford NLP tagging demo page?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I would like to reproduce the POS tagging shown here:

```
http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp
```

They say they use the englishPCFG.ser.gz parser, but it is not specified which tagger they used, and other properties.

So which command line to should I run to replicate the same tagging of the demo page? Currently I use:

```
java -Xmx500m -cp "*:/models/stanford-english-corenlp-2018-02-27-models.jar" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer  -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos -port 9001 -timeout 15000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java -Xmx5g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,parse -file example.txt -outputFormat text
```

If you don't specify a part of speech model the `parser` annotator will use the parsing algorithm to generate part of speech tags.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add a server property (can be done in the properties file):

```
enforceRequirements = false
```